# What is the difference between "закат" and "заход"?

Tags: выбор-слова

Could you please describe situation, when one word should be used instead of other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Заход солнца* only means the descent of the sun below the horizon (or the time of it).

But *Закат* has all the meanings which the word *Sunset* has:

1. the descent of the sun
2. what the sky looks like, when the sun goes down
3. the final stage (figurative)
4. the west (metaphor)

So when talking about astronomy, we usually say *заход солнца* (though *закат солнца* is OK too) but in all other cases it's simply *закат*.

It's also worth noting that both *закат*, *заход* and *запад* (the west) are made by the same pattern: *roll beyond*, *go beyond* and *fall beyond* respectively. But based on its meaning only *закат* appears to be a highly poetic word. A couple of examples from the well-known songs:

> Звезда надежды благодатная,
>   Звезда любви волшебных дней.
>   Ты будешь вечно *незакатная*
>   В душе тоскующей моей.
>   <sub>from the romance "Shine, shine, my star", words by V. Tchuevsky</sub>
>
> Лишь по небу тихо
>   Сползла погодя
>   На бархат *заката*
>   Слезинка дождя...
>   <sub>from "Grenada" by M. Svetlov</sub>
>
> Мимо белого яблока луны,
>   Мимо красного яблока *заката*,
>   Облака из неведомой страны,
>   К нам спешат и опять бегут куда-то.
>   <sub>from children's song "Beside moon's white apple...", words by S. Kozlov</sub>

Comment: Not "the West" (which usually means Europe and North America) but "the west", e.g. direction where the Sun sets.

Answer (score 3):

В переносном смысле используется "закат":

> На **закате** своей карьеры он...

.  В прямом (когда речь идёт о солнце) они равноупотребимы.

---

When speaking figuratively, use "**закат**".  When speaking of the astronomical event, they are interchangeable.

Also, there is another meaning of "*заход*", having to do with navigation ("круиз по Карибскому морю с **заходом** на Кубу"), there you'd not use '*закат*', of course.

Answer (score 0):

Word for word meaning:

> Закат ~ Rolldown / Rollback - property of rolling - заКАТ - катиться
>   Заход ~ Turndown / Turnback - property of common case turing - заХОД - ходить

Semantic meaning:

> Закат - is more lyric
>   Заход - is more pragmatic